# Finding Linear Map?

Tags: matrices

The temperature distribution on a metal plate is given by $T:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $T(x,y)=x^2+y^3$.

Write down the temperature gradient field, that is, the matrix of the linear map $DT$ at a general point $(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Comment: **Hint:**

For a mapping $f:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ the differential of $f$ is given by
$$Df=\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}&\tfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}&\ldots&\tfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\\tfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}&\tfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}&\ldots&\tfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\tfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1}&\tfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_2}&\ldots&\tfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}\end{bmatrix}$$
Where $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_m$ are the component functions.

Comment: What would I do after I calculate all the required derivatives? @ÁngelMarioGallegos

Comment: After that you can find the matrix corresponding to the linear mapping $Df$ in the point $\mathbf{x}_0=(x_0^1,x_0^2,\ldots,x_0^2)$.